# Rails condition where association has_many has count more than one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Package.rb

```
has_many :deals
```

Deal.rb

```
belongs_to package
```

Now simple question is I want to get all packages where deals count is more than one.
What is the best method to do it? `where(:available_for_purchase => true)`and `self.deals.count > 0`

(package.rb)

```
  class << self
    def available
      where(:available_for_purchase => true)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def self.available
  joins(:deals).where(:available_for_purchase => true).uniq
end
```

Joining the `deals` association will remove `Packages` without any deals ... SQL is doing the hard work here.

Then use :

```
Package.available
```

Comment: I got the wrong number of packages, instead of 3 it returns 8?

Comment: Edited my answer, forgot to group by id to remove duplicates

Comment: why i cant do the following? Package.available.count ?

Comment: Edited my answer to use `uniq` instead of `group`. Then, if you want the total of available packages, use `Package.available.length` since asking SQL for a count while grouping will give you subtotals per package.

Comment: But since its an activerecord query, why i can not use count? I can loop through results, why count is giving error?

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a counter-cache to give you the deal count as a column on the Package model, which will then let you use SQL for conditions.

Package.rb

```
has_many :deals
def with_deals
  where("deals_count > 0")
end
```

Deal.rb

```
belongs_to :package, :counter_cache => true
```

Then you can just call:

```
Package.with_deals
```

You can see an example of how to setup counter cache here:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column